# Ruby regex is modifying the user input when gsub using regex in regional languages?

Tags: regex, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, hindi

I am using Ruby regex to filter the user input to allow only numerics and alphabets of any language. But for some words the spelling is different after using regex.
ex:

```
text = 'कंप्यूटर'
regex = /[^(\p{Alpha})]/
filter_text = text.gsub(regex, '') #return result कंपयूटर
```

You can see the input and output are different. How to resolve the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```rb
regex = /[^\p{L}\p{Nd}\p{M}]+/
```

It will match any one or more chars other than Unicode letters or digits.

`\p{Nd}` matches all Unicode characters in the [*'Number, Decimal Digit'* category](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm), `\p{L}` matches all Unicode letters and `\p{M}` matches any diacritic marks.

See the [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/CPvdtc):

```rb
text = 'कंप्यूटर'
regex = /[^\p{L}\p{Nd}\p{M}]+/
filter_text = text.gsub(regex, '')
puts filter_text
# => कंप्यूटर
```